# Recommended method for recognising Browser's HTML5 capability?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var isH5 = !! document.createElement('canvas').getContext
```

Would you say, that above JS code snippet is a good method of recognising a Browser's HTML5 capability?

Also see [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) in case of IE quirks mode, it should still return `false`.

**Update:** Thanks for all the Modernizr links, we are using above recognising logic in conjunction with Modernizr already.

Comment: Use Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to use something  `Modernizr` to  detection .Modernizr is an open source, MIT-licensed JavaScript library that detects support for many HTML5 & CSS3 features. If there isnt support, it returns `false`

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) {
  // logic
} else {
  // your message
}
```

Comment: Include modernizr.js from modernizr.com then use @hamala94 code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was also asking if the solution I proposed is good, apart from the recommended Modernizr.